# Customise Sitecore RichTextEditor to add default wrapper

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, rich-text-editor

The front end (html and css) is set up such a way that for the description text from a Sitecore content field needs to have a `<p>` tag wrapped around it.

So by default the RTE wraps texts in a `<p>` tag = TRUE. BUT the catch is you will need to hit  <kbd>Enter</kbd> or copy/paste multiple paragraphs.

How can we force Sitecore to add a P tag if it's just one line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortunately, From the dll, one particular function caught my eye:

```cs
protected virtual void SetupScripts()
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in Factory.GetConfigNodes("clientscripts/htmleditor/script"))
    this.Result.Scripts.AppendFormat("<script src=\"{0}\" language=\"{1}\"></script>\n", (object) XmlUtil.GetAttribute("src", node), (object) XmlUtil.GetAttribute("language", node));
}
```

NICE, eh? The developers of SITECORE are clever after all.
So I did this in the web.config,

```xml
<!— CLIENT SCRIPTS
These script files are included in the client, e.g. '<script src="/myscript.js" language="JavaScript"/>'
—>
<clientscripts>
    <everypage />
    <htmleditor>
        <script src=”/assets/js/CustomRTE.js” language=”javascript”/>
    </htmleditor>
</clientscripts>
```

And overrode `scSendRequest` function from EditorWindow.aspx.

```js
window.scSendRequest = function(evt, command) {
    var editor = scRichText.getEditor();
    if (editor.get_mode() == 2) { //If in HTML edit mode
        editor.set_mode(1); //Set mode to Design
    }
    var htmls = editor.get_html(true);
    var regex = /<p[^>]*>.*?<\/p>/i;
    var match = regex.exec(htmls);
    if(match == null && htmls != null) {
        htmls = "<p>" + htmls + "</p>";
    }

    //$("EditorValue").value = editor.get_html(true);
    $("EditorValue").value = htmls;

    scForm.browser.clearEvent(evt);

    scForm.postRequest("", "", "", command);

    return false;
}
```

AND YAY .. double rainbow and unicorn.

Comment: The EditorWindow.aspx didn't work for me. I had to add the same override to EditorPage.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own custom solution for this requirement as well.
You could create a new pipeline event in the

- `<saveRichTextContent>` pipeline - This could enable you to append the

  tag when you hit save on the rich text editor in sitecore
- `<renderField>` pipeline - This could on the fly wrap your text into `<p></p>` tags while rendering the page, if the

  tag was not there in the original rtf text.

---

If you go for method 1: `<saveRichTextContent>`

You could add to the pipeline in web.config:

```xml
<processor type="Sitecore72.Classes.WrapRichTextInParagraphOnSave, Sitecore72" />
```

And you could use the following corresponding code:

```cs
namespace Sitecore72.Classes
{
    public class WrapRichTextInParagraphOnSave
    {
        public void Process(SaveRichTextContentArgs args)
        {
            if (!(args.Content.Trim().StartsWith("<p>") && args.Content.Trim().EndsWith("</p>")))
                args.Content = "<p>" + args.Content + "</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, that this pipeline gets triggered only when you use the Show Editor buttong of a rich text field:

### [image: Show Editor]

If you go for method 2: `<renderField>`

To append to this pipeline you would use this config:

```xml
<processor type="Sitecore72.Classes.WrapRichTextInParagraphOnRender, Sitecore72" />
```

And you could use the following corresponding code:

```cs
namespace Sitecore72.Classes
{
    public class WrapRichTextInParagraphOnRender
    {
        public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            if (args.FieldTypeKey == "rich text" && !(args.Result.FirstPart.Trim().StartsWith("<p>") && args.Result.FirstPart.Trim().EndsWith("</p>")))
                args.Result.FirstPart = "<p>" + args.Result.FirstPart + "</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

For both these, ensure you add reference to Sitecore.Kernel.dll and HtmlAgilityPack.dll. Both of these are available with the sitecore package solution.

Comment: In both cases I would check for more than just paragraph tags, but also other elements such as table, div, ol and ul.